# Why are apps logging me in as someone else?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Device: Samsung Galaxy S II (i777) running Cyanogenmod 10 nightly 20120929

I'm having a very strange issue that I'm hoping someone else has seen before. In two separate apps, I'm being logged in as other users with no input from me. It first showed up in ESPN ScoreCenter, where it would identify me as someone else and import all their favorite teams.  This "someone else" would change somewhat regularly (I didn't look too close at this, but it seemed like it was different on a daily basis). I assumed this was an issue with the ScoreCenter app and contacted ESPN (they were less than helpful). I gave up on that one, and just assumed it was a bug. However, just recently I noticed that Scoreloop had a similar issue. In Cut the Rope, when I open Scoreloop, it identifies me as someone else again. I initially submitted a ticket to Scoreloop, but this morning noticed it was logged in as someone else, just like the ScoreCenter app did.

I saw this same issue when using Cyanogenmod 9. I'm not sure when it started exactly, but now that I'm seeing it in two separate apps, I'm starting to think it's an issue with my phone, my ROM, or some Android piece that both apps tie into. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happen to me with some apps...

Did you lost your IMEI?

I mean, maybe in the process of rooting, sim-unlocking, rom updating your phone, etc... you did something wrong and "lost your IMEI". It seems having an IMEI of 004999010640000 indicates so. At least this happened to me with my Galaxy S (I9000)

Some apps seem to uniquely identify a user by IMEI. If you have this 004999010640000 IMEI you are now part of a club of hundreds with that exact same wrong IMEI. So someone who also "lost his IMEI" might have registered to those apps before. This happened to me with OpenFeint for example.

To check your IMEI go to Settings > About phone > Status

Comment: Ah, yes. I do have the "generic" IMEI. I believe it happened when I got a warranty replacement device, as shortly after I was temporarily suspended because my device was supposedly stolen. I'm guessing I should look to fix that. I found an XDA thread about Docomo-modified devices, but is there something relevant to the general AT&T i777?

Comment: No idea, about that, sorry. I've seen some threads about recovering lost IMEI's but never tried yet. Probably because it has not been much of a problem for me yet :D